# MvvmCross Windows Phone 8 (Silverlight) crash with 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException'

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, mvvmcross

I've created new project with VS2013 + Xamarin:

- MyProject Core (as Class Library Portable, only without Silverlight
  5)
- MyProject WindowsPhone (as Silverlight Windows Phone 8.0)

then I follow tutorial from [Stuart Lodge MvvmCross tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLR6WI6W1JdeYSXLbm58jwAKYT7RQR31-W&feature=player_detailpage&v=_DHDMNB_IeY)

and can't run Windows Phone 8 build with System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException

I also add debug exception for this. What's most important - it is working on Windows Phone 8.1 emulator, but not on Windows Phone 8.0 (for example 720p)

Comment: Also it's connected with "Cannot create instance of type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryContext' [Line: 5 Position: 79] ---> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented."

Comment: Please show us the code or we won't be able to help.